# Вставка значения из списка в ячейку таблицы HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы выбранное значение в списке, добавлялось в ячейку где расположен список?

```js
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td')
    .text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td> <!-- Нужная ячейка -->
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>";
        <option>2</option>";
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>test
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *В книге какого автора есть герой, которого как зовут?*

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td > select').change(e => $(e.target).replaceWith(e.target.value));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]